# Unable to customize VueDatePicker

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs3

```
<template>
    <VueDatePicker v-model="date" ref="datepicker" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const date = ref();
const datepicker = ref(null);

const yourCustomMethod = () => {
    if (datepicker) {
      // Close the menu programmatically
      datepicker.value.closeMenu()
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to customize the VueDatePicker with the implementation mentioned above, but I get an error saying that closeMenu() does not exist in type 'never'. I followed the implementation according to the VueDatePicker documentation, so I can't figure out where the problem is.

I want to solve this issue.

Comment: Your code is not for TypeScript and it works as it is. Your problem comes from TypeScript solution. Please consider to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using some code sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

you can maybe juste add this condition :

```
if (datepicker?.value) {
   // Close the menu programmatically
   datepicker.value.closeMenu()
}
```

I tried to reproduce your problem here https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-ully-qg6xpo?file=/src/App.vue, but everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do something like this.

```
import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
const element = ref<InstanceType<typeof VueDatePicker> | null>(null)
```

OR

```
const element = ref(null as unknown as HTMLElement); // ref<HTMLElement>();
```